# How can I use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage to document Entity Framework data models if they are constantly over-written?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I have been tasked with documenting our API using code comments and the *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage* package.

The problem is that we use Entity Framework and the classes we use for our data models are auto-generated, and will be over-written the next time the model is updated. When this happens my code comments (and therefore my documentation) will be lost.

What is the best way to use *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage* with Entity Framework?

Comment: I would think that you document the controller classes. Your EF functions should be one or more layers behind the controllers.

Comment: We do document the controller classes, and that works fine. But the data objects they return also need to be documented. Those data objects are auto-generated by EF.

Comment: Are you returning EF entities from your controllers?

Comment: It looks like in some cases, yes we are.

Comment: Outside of doing something wonky like re-introducing a property with the new keyword in a derived class and invoking the base member you don't have many options. If it were my project, I would return only plain poco responses from the controllers. You can find a number of mappers to map from your EF entities to a new set of service layer entities. You can then decorate/localize/annotate your front facing service entities without even caring about your how the data layer is doing things. I know this doesn't answer your question but I thought I would share my 2 cents.

Comment: The EF classes are generated as partial classes. You can add other partial classes that are not overwritten.

Comment: You could also look into T4 tooling to auto-comment your auto-generated classes. However, I think this would be synonymous to "the tail wagging the dog."

Comment: Can you switch to code-first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NuGet to install the **`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`** package

1. install this nuget [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/)
2. add `using System.Web.Routing;` to Global.asax
3. add **`AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`** to  **Application_Start()** in Global.asax
4. build Project
5. Right click on project name and select properties
6. in build selection check **Xml documention file**
7. set to `App_Data/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME.xml`
8. save project
9. go to **Areas>HelpPage>App_Start>HelpPageConfig** Uncomment line 37 to use the documentation from XML documentation file.

   ```
   config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME.xml")));
   ```
10. end